# Spark-submit not picking modules and sub-modules of project structure

Tags: pyspark, pycharm, spark-submit

Folder structure of pyspark project on pycharm:

```
TEST
    TEST (marked as sources root)
        com
            earl
                test
                    pysprk
                        utils
                            utilities.py
                        test_main.py
```

test_main.py has:

```
from _ast import arg

__author__ = "earl"
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_json, struct, lit
from com.earl.test.pyspark.utils.utilities import *
import sys
```

utilities.py has:

```
__author__ = "earl"

from py4j.protocol import Py4JJavaError
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import sys
```

On PyCharm, I execute the code by Running `test_main.py` and it works absolutley OK. Calls functions from `utilities.py` and executes perfectly. I set `Run -> Edit Configurations -> Parameters` on PyCharm as `D:\Users\input\test.json localhost:9092` and use `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]` and it does it OK

Spark submit command:

```
spark-submit --master local --conf spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel=WARN --name test D:\Users\earl\com\earl\test\pyspark\test_main.py --files D:\Users\earl\com\test\pyspark\utils\utilities.py D:\Users\input\test.json localhost:9092
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\earl\com\earl\test\pyspark\test_main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from com.earl.test.pyspark.utils.utilities import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by setting below property before running spark-submit.

PYTHONPATH earlier is set as `%PY_HOME%\Lib;%PY_HOME%\DLLs;%PY_HOME%\Lib\lib-tk`

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;D:\Users\earl\TEST\ (Path of the project home structure)
```

And updated `spark-submit` as (Only main needed to be mentioned):

```
spark-submit --master local --conf spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel=WARN --name test D:\Users\earl\com\earl\test\pyspark\test_main.py D:\Users\input\test.json localhost:9092
```